# Clean up code and keep null values from crashing read.csv.sql

Tags: sql, r, conditional-statements, read.csv

I am using `read.csv.sql` to conditionally read in data (my data set is extremely large so this was the solution I chose to filter it and reduce it in size prior to reading the data in). I was running into memory issues by reading in the full data and then filtering it so that is why it is important that I use the conditional read so that the subset is read in, versus the full data set.

Here is a small data set so my problem can be reproduced:

```
write.csv(iris, "iris.csv", row.names = F)
library(sqldf)
csvFile <- "iris.csv"
```

I am finding that the notation you have to use is extremely awkward using `read.csv.sql` the following is the how I am reading in the file:

```
# Step 1 (Assume these values are coming from UI)
spec <- 'setosa'
petwd <- 0.2

# Add quotes and make comma-separated:
spec <- toString(sprintf("'%s'", spec)) 
petwd <- toString(sprintf("'%s'", petwd)) 

# Step 2 - Conditionally read in the data, store in 'd'
d <- fn$read.csv.sql(csvFile, sql='select * from file where 
                                  "Species" in ($spec)'
                                  and "Petal.Width" in ($petwd)',
                     filter = list('gawk -f prog', prog = '{ gsub(/"/, ""); print }'))
```

My *main* problem is that if any of the values above (from UI) are null then it won't read in the data properly, because this chunk of code is all hard coded.
I would like to change this into: Step 1 - check which values are null and do not filter off of them, then filter using `read.csv.sql` for all non-null values on corresponding columns.

**Note:** I am reusing the code from this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52839580/notation-issues-with-read-csv-sql-in-r) within this question.

**UPDATE**
I want to clear up what I am asking. This is what I am trying to do:

If a field, say `spec` comes through as `NA` (meaning the user did not pick input) then I want it to filter as such (default to `spec == EVERY SPEC`):

```
# Step 2 - Conditionally read in the data, store in 'd'
d <- fn$read.csv.sql(csvFile, sql='select * from file where 
                                  "Petal.Width" in ($petwd)',
                     filter = list('gawk -f prog', prog = '{ gsub(/"/, ""); print }'))
```

Since `spec` is `NA`, if you try to filter/read in a file matching `spec == NA` it will read in an empty data set since there are no NA values in my data, hence breaking the code and program. Hope this clears it up more.

Comment: Why not add a null check and replace with default value?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems:

- some of the simplifications provided in the link in the question were not followed.
- `spec` is a scalar so one can just use `'$spec'`
- `petwd` is a numeric scalar and SQL does not require quotes around numbers so just use `$petwd`
- the question states you want to handle empty fields but not how so we have used csvfix to map them to -1 and also strip off quotes.  (Alternately let them enter  and do it in R.  Empty numerics will come through as 0 and empty character fields will come through as zero length character fields.)
- you can use [...] in place of "..." in SQL

The code below worked for me in both Windows and Ubuntu Linux with the bash shell.

```
library(sqldf)

spec <- 'setosa'
petwd <- 0.2

d <- fn$read.csv.sql(
  "iris.csv", 
  sql = "select * from file where [Species] = '$spec' and [Petal.Width] = $petwd", 
  verbose = TRUE, 
  filter = 'csvfix map -smq -fv "" -tv -1'
)
```

### Update

Regarding the update at the end of the question it was clarified that the NA could be in `spec` as opposed to being in the data being read in and that if `spec` is NA then the condition involving `spec` should be regarded as TRUE.  In that case just expand the SQL `where` condition to handle that as follows.

```
spec <- NA
petwd <- 0.2

d <- fn$read.csv.sql(
  "iris.csv", 
  sql = "select * from file 
         where ('$spec' == 'NA' or [Species] = '$spec') and [Petal.Width] = $petwd", 
  verbose = TRUE, 
  filter = 'csvfix echo -smq'
)
```

The above will return all rows for which `Petal.Width` is 0.2 .

Comment: I updated the question to reflect why and how to handle NA's.

Comment: Have added Update at end of answer.