# how to filter double quotes when creating SQL file with read.csv.sql, R

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

After much searching and experimenting, I simply cannot get this. I have a csv whose fields are all within quotation marks and I cannot import them. My basic script is the following. It works fine if there are no quotes. I would expect it to print out just the first three lines. I am thinking it could be the filter argument that I need to add?

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("attach testingdb as new")
read.csv.sql("df.csv", sql = "create table main as select * from file", dbname = "testingdb")
sqldf("select * from main limit 3", dbname = "testingdb")
```

**This is what the two few lines of the csv look like:**

"{6DA08449}","89000","2002-05-10 00:00","MK42Q","S","N","F","38",""
"{6DB08449}","100000","2002-05-10 00:00","M429HQ","S","N","F","38",""

Comment: [`sqldf` FAQ 13: How does one deal with quoted fields in `read.csv.sql`?](https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf/blob/master/README.md#13-how-does-one-deal-with-quoted-fields-in-readcsvsql).

Comment: i saw this one. It seems to be more for windows .... and Im mac.

Comment: It's not an OS issue, it's a limitation in sqlite regardless of the platform. Though the examples use `tr.exe`, just use `tr` and see if it works.

Comment: There was recently a similar question with several alternative solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52839580/notation-issues-with-read-csv-sql-in-r/52839896#52839896

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52882551/clean-up-code-and-keep-null-values-from-crashing-read-csv-sql/52920980#52920980

Comment: thanks for looking at that. it could be that I can solve this problem with some of the codes, but I wonder if I am getting a problem next with the "}" brackets. I think the easiest solution may be to just clean the text.